# Help with complex analysis series question that's troubling me

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

[image]

-What does it mean for a series to be 'absolutely' convergent?
-what does the notation (Zn)n denote?

Struggling with this question any help is appreciated bu a solution would be much appreicated! Thanks

Comment: Since this question is obviously from a textbook, I am 100% certain that the textbook also defines what absolutelly convergent means.

Comment: It's not from a textbook, my lecturer made it up. And I'm struggling interpreting the lecture notes he's made.
Zn is a complex series right? what does |Zn| converges mean if Zn converges.

Comment: Oh, but then your teacher has treated the concepts of absolute convergence before. Or not?

Comment: @5xsum, I guess you are right, but I think to give a small hint about wikipedia is useful.

Answer (score 1):

For the first google is your friend:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence

The notation $(z_n)_n$ means an arbitrary series. The remark means that you can use the fact that for an arbitrary sequence $(z_n)_n$ with the mentioned property
also the limit of the real....